# Does conduit have to go against wall or be supported in a crawlspace?

Tags: electrical

I live in East Texas, and I plan to send my service entry to the house panel above the floor as pictured. Are there any code violations routing it like this? It looks awkward. My other question is, which of these three black wires is neutral? Shouldn't it be marked?

(FYI wire is not in conduit yet)

[image]

Comment: For starters, you'll need to remove the LB cover and pull the wires in that direction.  The photo looks like a pull through an incomplete conduit, which it is, but at least the required body is in place.

Comment: Even if this is compliant (IDK) why wouldn't you add some support and protection?

Comment: I will add something, I'm just wondering. @RobertChapin what are you talking about? Why would the cover have to come off?

Comment: Code requires the conduit be finished, then the wires are pulled though.

Comment: @MichaelRader - you want to pull the cable using the opening available to pull anything else in the future. So, undo the cover on the box on the lower right and use that opening for pulls. Who ran the wires and where are they coming from? How are the marked on that end?

Comment: Can we imagine that the person who pulled the service wires installed and used the LB correctly, and *then* left the wires this way in order to temporarily keep the cover and screws in a safe place?  It seems harsh in this case to assume the wires were pulled improperly.  The run to the panel will be completed before the next section of pull is done, also correctly

Comment: @JonCuster man i'm so confused. The wires are coming out of the wall here, from a main cut-ff and going to a main subpanel inside the house through the floor. Why does the cover need to come off? These service wires are already pulled through it and will be sent into the verticle conduit in the photo.

Comment: @MichaelRader I believe there is an allegation that the wires were pulled improperly by *not* using the LB cover for access.  IMO that is a harsh reading of the photo and a distraction here.  You are welcome to ignore it.  The question and photo are good!  You could add a photo of the *ends* of the cable to show (if) none of them are marked.  That should be done after they are cut and trimmed in the panel but it sure would be helpful it if were done here temporarily.

Comment: @jay613 Yeah none of them are marked for some reason. Hired an electrician to pull these into the house. I'll have to find neutral the dangerous way when the time comes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it needs to be supported. But only for longer distances. See [this site for a table](http://wiresizecalculator.net/tables/conduitsupportstable.htm).

Hard to say exactly what's what without (a) wire size and (b) conduit size. But based on likely wire size, I will assume for the moment that the conduit is between 1-1/4" and 2" in diameter. In which case it can go 5 feet between supports. The vertical part is (hopefully) supported from the top. And my guess is that the curved horizontal section has no more than 2 feet between the wall (which supports it) and the vertical part.

As far as the neutral question:

If the wires are already connected at the other end (but breaker off...) then just check which wire has continuity with ground. If the wires are not yet connected at the other end, pick a wire and test to figure out which wire is which before connecting either end.

Comment: Isn't an inspector going to whack him for "subject to physical damage"?

Comment: That depends on the type of conduit. I can't tell (maybe others can) whether this Schedule 40 or Schedule 80.

Comment: Supposing it's schedule 80, wouldn't it still likely fail?

Comment: Why? My understanding is that Schedule 80 can be used in areas subject to damage.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but is that box required?  It seems it would be easy to turn that sweep 90 degrees and do away with the box.  Probably a future idea/next time.

Comment: Maybe. But once it is already there and paid for, it really doesn't hurt to have it.

Comment: @crip659 it wasn't enough to get me straight under the hole. I added it because I had it on hand and it worked out well.

Comment: You're right on the physical damage. I viscerally reacted against the design. It reminded me of the receptacles that I have sticking out of my yard under NEC 314.23. 314.23E imposes a minimum distance from the conduit body to the support of 3'-0".